# How to get value from JSON file and use it for maths operations

Tags: python, json, linux

I have a site where it has a .txt file, I need to pull this JSON stored in a .txt file and do maths operations with them, how do I pull these values exactly?

For example, I have the contents of the `y.txt`:

```
{'item1': a, 'price:' 1.00}
{'item2': b, 'price:' 2.00}
```

How can we just get only both the price attribute from these 2 items and their values (2+1)

```
import json
import requests

url = "https://x.com/y.txt"
data = requests.get(url)

// some math operations here
'price': 1 + 'price' : 2

//then store the results of this operation in another variable
```

Answer (score 0):

To load json data you would use json.loads(text_that_is_json) this would return an object structured according to the json that was decoded and you could access the values as they were structured in the json. The examples you give are not valid json. Strings should be in double not single quotes and a and b aren't quoted at all and the colon for price is inside quotes instead of outside. Additionally json stands for javascript object notation and it is expected that what is parsed is a single object. If all the other errors are fixed it appears the text file has multiple objects defined. From your example it looks like it is one object per line so you'd want to split the text file by newlines and then parse each line with a separate call to json.loads. For example:

```
item = json.loads('{"item1":"a","price":1.00}')
item["item1"] == "a" #True
item["price"] == 1.00 # True
```

If you have control over the txt file in question you should create it with json.dumps to fix the formatting issues (just pass an object that can be converted to json ie made up of lists dictionaries and types that would be considered simple types in C++/java,) you should also not have dynamic key names like item1 and item2 I think what you really want is item_name or item_code or something so you can always get that first value without having to check what keys are defined in the dictionary.